# button not taking Angular Material UI theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an component with a button:

`<button mat-button (click)='submit()' [disabled]='btnDisabled'>Save changes</button>`

According to the [Angular Material UI](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview) docs giving the `mat-button` attribute this should be enough to give it the Material UI styling, but the button is not changing.

In my `angular.json` file I have:

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
```

```
// styles.scss

/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@use './custom-theme'
```

```
// custom-theme.scss

// Custom Theming for Angular Material
// For more information: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat.core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$theme-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$theme-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$theme-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

// Create the theme object. A theme consists of configurations for individual
// theming systems such as "color" or "typography".
$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $theme-primary,
    accent: $theme-accent,
    warn: $theme-warn,
  )
));

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

What am I missing? Why isn't the button changing style?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I missed the Angular Material Module import:

Created a file:

```
// material.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

And imported it in my `app.module.ts`